# How can I choose randomly from five Mix RGB nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have five separate color ramps for leaf colors and I want
the leaves to choose their colors randomly.

My setup looks like this:

[image]

But this doesn’t work as I want:

[image]

I want it to looks like this:

[image]

But with my gradients.

I tried adding a round math node after the object info, but that didn't have any effect.

---

Thanks to Allen Simpson, it works!

[image]

Comment: Then it just looks like the last photo and I want that nice gradient to be on these leafes

Comment: ok my bad I misunderstood

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but in your case you could have just 1 color ramp in Black & White and just change the *color* with a mix RGB set to "Color" and use the factor the same way. My 2 cents

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, or just defining a hue range to go into HSV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned, if you can combine your color choices into one ramp, you can plug the Random output directly into that.  To do this with this level of control, you need to do some math to convert the random output into a straight 0 or 1 over a given range.  I've done this with a compare node.

[image]

The bottom compare node is everything in the range of .8 to 1.0, which, at the end of this group, is the same as the top color input (that top input is the 'default' case, or in other words "everything that's not caught by these other compare nodes").  That's why it's not connected to anything.

Comment: Works just I wanted, thanks!