# Separate HSV missing in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, color

I need to access a color´s HSV values separately in geometry nodes, I´m using Blender 3.2.1 and there only seems to be a separate RGB node and no separate HSV.

Is there any way to convert RGB values to HSV?
Or am i missing something here?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by saying "as of Blender v3.2.1", there was no _Separate HSV_ in Blender 3.1.2 or 3.0.0 either in _Geometry Nodes_, I just checked that. It's always been in the _Shader Editor_ only (and it still is in 3.2.1).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann my bad, non-native speaker here. I just wanted to state the version I´m using as I hoped there might be an experimental branch with the HSV node

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212430/how-to-convert-hsv-to-rgb-using-shader-nodes has some info on recreating Blender's separate HSV for shader nodes using only math and mix, which should work for GN as well.  There are plenty of separate HSV algorithms available, but they don't all give identical output.  Easiest, if it's possible, would be to simply make an HSV version of any textures, using compositing or by making a render with a plane + modified material....

Comment: Related: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the same math as Blender's source code, it's possible to make these node groups:

RGB to HSV:

[image]

HSV to RGB:

[image]

[image]

The nodes and the node groups outputs the same color:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hero! Someone had to do it :)

Comment: Holy shit, you knocked it out of the park with this one. Thank you so much!