# How to add 3 gradients ColorRamp random to my object?

Tags: color, random

How to add 3 random ColorRamp gradients to my object?

I have multiple buckets, how to add 3 colorramps gradients randomly to my object?

I can not do it.[image: How to add 3 random ColorRamp gradients to my object?]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/205795/110840

Comment: @AllenSimpson thanks Allen

Comment: not a problem, friend