# Procedural material for corrosion

Tags: materials, procedural

I am modeling some small stainless steel parts that have pitting corrosion on the surface. The pits look like small needle pokes randomly positioned on the surface. [image: actual_photo]

I have tried using the Noise texture with color ramps but I cannot get a precise pit. I have tried proportional editing but cannot manipulate at a fine enough scale.

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from a freely attributable "Lemon" material I have...

[image]

[image]

You job: fool around with the various scale parameters... [image]

Comment: Thanks! I think I can get what I want using this.

Comment: @johnmerrill -- I also see you only want the pockmarks in limited locations, perhaps randomly.   Some material topics like [random mix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/205794/111042) might be useful.